# My useFetch with typescript is giving me "Property does not exist" warnings

Tags: typescript, nuxtjs3

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    const { data, pending, refresh, error } = useFetch( () => `/api/abc` ) 
    if(data.value?.success && data.value?.models?.length > 0){
        ...
    }
```

This code occurs errors(warnings) around `.seccess` and `?.models` in my jetbrains tool.

The error message are

`TS2339 : Property 'success' does not exist on type {}`

`TS2339 : Property 'models' does not exist on type {}`

This code works fine. But I don't want to see any errors in my jetbrain editor.
how can i solve it?

---

```
interface fetchData { 
    value?: any 
} 
const { data, pending, refresh, error }: {data:fetchData, pending:any, refresh:any, error:any } = 
...
```

When I "type" my code, the error is disappeared. But how can I shorten it?

Comment: If you don't care about TS, you could disable those. Otherwise, you will need to type your code.

Comment: How can I type my code?
"interface fetchData {
 value?: any
}
const { data, pending, refresh, error }: {data:fetchData, pending:any, refresh:any, error:any } =  " like this?? / How can I shorten it?

Comment: Yeah, actual types rather than `any` could be better tho. You need to learn how to Typescript to make it properly. `any` is kinda just an "ignore it" kind of type.

Comment: If you're spamming with `any`, you're basically not using TS. So disable it, will be faster/better.